# Polar Wearlink Bluetooth packet

Tags: android, bluetooth, packet

i am looking at the code of a project called MyTracks:

http://code.google.com/r/jrgert-polar-bluetooth/source/browse/MyTracks/src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/services/sensors/PolarMessageParser.java?r=ebc01faf49550bc9801633ff38bb3b8ddd6f5698

Now I am having problems with the method `isValid(byte[] buffer)`. I don´t understand what exactly is he checking here. We want to know if the first byte in the array is the header containing 0xFE. I don´t quite understand the following lines :

```
 boolean goodHdr = ((buffer[0] & 0xFF) == 0xFE);
 boolean goodChk = ((buffer[2] & 0xFF) == (0xFF - (buffer[1] & 0xFF)));
 return goodHdr && goodChk;
```

any ideas?

Comment: This seemss strange. someValue & 0xFF is always equal to someValue (0 <= someValue <= 0xff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

&0xff simply converts signed byte to unsigned int for doing the comparison

Comment: You should elaborate better to let everyone understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ewoks is correct, refer to this blog post:

http://ww.telent.net/2012/5/3/listening_to_a_polar_bluetooth_hrm_in_linux

"Digging into src/com/google/android/apps/mytracks/services/sensors/PolarMessageParser.java we find a helpful comment revealing that, notwithstanding Polar's ridiculous stance on giving out development info (they don't, is the summary) the Wearlink packet format is actually quite simple.

Polar Bluetooth Wearlink packet example

Hdr - Len -  Chk - Seq - Status - HeartRate - RRInterval_16-bits

FE -  08  -  F7 - 06  -   F1     -  48        -   03 64

where

- Hdr always = 254 (0xFE),
- Chk = 255 - Len
- Seq range 0 to 15
- Status = Upper nibble may be battery voltage
- bit 0 is Beat Detection flag."

Answer (score 0):

First line is checking is received buffer are starting with 0xFE as it should be with this Polar Wearable.

Second line is checking if length byte is correct as well because it's value by specification is 255-value writen is size byte..

This together is super simple verification that messages are correct (more complicated implementation would include CRC or other verification methods). cheers